# Edit MYSQL records using jsp form

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I have an index page (`index.jsp`) that prints out the ID number of people stored in `newtable`. This works ok.

**index.jsp**

```
 try {
     out.println("Connection Successful...");
     mystmt = myConn.createStatement();
     myrs = mystmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM records.newtable");
     while (myrs.next())
         out.println("</br>"+myrs.getInt("ID")+"<a href=\"editrecord.jsp\"> Edit </a>);
}
```

I have added an edit link that appears after each ID returned. The edit link is pointing at `editrecord.jsp`. I would like to be able to update the **firstname and lastname** of the ID I selected with the original value displayed in the input box. Has anyone any ideas? I have no issues connecting to the database. Cheers.

**editform.jsp**

```
 <p>First name: <br>
 <input name="fn" value= <%out.println(myrs.getString("FIRSTNAME"));%>></p>

 <p>Last name: <br>
 <input name="ln" value=<%out.println(myrs.getString("LASTNAME"));%>></p>

 <br/><input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to make an ajax call based on the click.

Go and fetch the row and fill the UI fields based on the data received.

```
 onclick="fillFields(pass_id_here)";
```

JS (just to get an idea of how it will work):

```
function fillFields(id){

 $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: 'URL THAT CAN RETURN JSON OF THE RECORD ROW',
        data: {id:id},
        success: function(response){
            var resultData  = JSON.parse(response);
             $("#firstName").val(resultData.firstName);
             $("#lastName").val(resultData.lastName);
    });

}
```

**OR maybe:**

On click you can reload the page and send the row data on the view and fill the fields.